# Found another file with the destination path - where is that other file?

Tags: python, django

When running `manage.py collectstatic` in Django, I see messages like:

```
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/jquery.init.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

I tried running `find . -type l` to search for symbolic links in my Django project, but it didn't turn up anything.

How can I figure out where the other file with the same destination path is?

Comment: Have you looked in whatever dir's are defined in the `STATIC_DIRS` setting?

Comment: related https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/720

Comment: it looks like you have at least two of such files 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' 
those files may be in app directrories - look in site-packages (where all your modules are installed)

Answer (score 11):

Like templates, static files are searched for in two locations:

1. under the directories listed in `STATIC_DIRS`
2. in static directories in the apps themselves.

In this case, it looks like this file is provided both by `django/contrib/admin/static`, and `/static/`.

Answer (score 9):

Django respects the order of your apps in `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` when running `collectstatic`.

If you have two installed apps that write the same static files (e.g. `django.contrib.admin` and `grappelli`) then Django `collectstatic` will write the static files for the app appearing *first* in the list. When it hits the second app it will ignore its static files and output the warning you are seeing.

So you need to find out which two `INSTALLED_APPS` are trying to write the same static files, and decide which one you want to use the static files of. If you make sure that app appears *first* in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list then you can safely ignore the warnings generated from the second app.

Answer (score 5):

check this: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/720

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',    #causes verbose duplicate notifications in django 1.9
)
```