# pythonanywhere // python manage.py collectstatic = 0 static files copied to // 175 unmodified

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

why my static files don't load?

CMD

```
/PruebaApettito.FINAL/PruebaApettito.FINAL-master/Prueba2/proyectoapettito (master)$ python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

/home/sagutierrezr95/PruebaApettito.FINAL/PruebaApettito.FINAL-master/Prueba2/proyectoapettito/AppApettito/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/collapse.min.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.

...
0 static files copied to '/home/sagutierrezr95/PruebaApettito.FINAL/PruebaApettito.FINAL-master/Prueba2/proyectoapettito/AppApettito/static', 175 unmodified.
```

SETTING

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sagutierrezr95.pythonanywhere.com']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/sagutierrezr95/PruebaApettito.FINAL/PruebaApettito.FINAL-master/Prueba2/proyectoapettito/AppApettito/static/'
```

I need the templates on my page but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. the route should be correct and not misspelle

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why my static files don't load

Comment: Hi Salvador, does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571256/found-another-file-with-the-destination-path-where-is-that-other-file - what does your INSTALLED_APPS look like?

Answer (score 0):

static_root instead this

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]`

You can use