# Django static files not consistent between DEBUG=True and after `collectstatic`

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-grappelli

My "Select all {amount} {model}s" action, which should be in the actions bar while viewing a model page in the Django admin, does not work in production.

Expected behaviour, as recorded running locally with `DEBUG=True` in `local_settings.py`:
[image: Django footer action bar showing a dropdown, then three buttons; "100 out of 100 selected", "Select all 3000 Films" and "Execute" all translated to Dutch.]

Behaviour on staging deployment and while running locally with `DEBUG=False`:
[image: Django footer action bar showing a dropdown, then three buttons; "0 out of 100 selected", then one offset slightly higher saying "100 out of 100 selected" and "Execute". There is no "Select all".]

I'm having issues with inconsistency between the static files my templates are working with between a local running of the `runserver` command with `DEBUG=True` vs. running the same codebase after running `collectstatic` and then running it with `DEBUG=False` in my settings.

The differences in static files is also apparent in the listed sources when inspecting the page.
Working correctly:

[image: Filesystem showing the file "actions.js"]

Not working correctly:

[image: Filesystem showing the file "actions.min.js"]

Running the `collectstatic` command gives me this output:

```
Loading .env environment variables...
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/actions.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

But locally, both `actions.js` and `actions.min.js` are present in my static files folder. I don't want to turn on DEBUG on the production deployments, but currently don't know how to solve this issue I'm having. All help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
My settings file was requested, so here's a version (cleaned of sensitive data):

```py
import os

DEBUG = False
MAINTENANCE_MODE = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE = os.getenv("K8_NAMESPACE", "")
DEPLOY_LOCATION = "testing"
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 604800  # A week
DATABASES: dict = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "NAME": f"[DB_NAME]",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "[PASSWORD]",
    }
}
DATABASES["readonly"] = DATABASES["default"].copy()
DATABASES["readonly"]["USER"] += "_readonly"
DATABASES["readonly"]["TEST"] = {"MIRROR": "default"}

UNICORN_VERSION = os.getenv("UNICORN_VERSION", "[COMPANY_NAME]")

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH.joinpath("static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH.joinpath("versions", UNICORN_VERSION, "static"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [PROJECT_PATH.joinpath("locale")]

# When a version defines a locale folder, it becomes the main
LOCALE_PATHS = getattr(version_settings, "LOCALE_PATHS", LOCALE_PATHS)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django_otp",
    "django_otp.plugins.otp_static",
    "django_otp.plugins.otp_totp",
    "two_factor",
    "grappelli",
    "grappelli_filters",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "rangefilter",
    "admin_numeric_filter",
    "admin_auto_filters",
    "api",
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found another file with the destination path - where is that other file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571256/found-another-file-with-the-destination-path-where-is-that-other-file)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The order already prioritises grappelli (which is what I want) and changing it either doesn't affect the behavior of the site, or breaks it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by updating my grappelli version from 2.15 to 3.0. I suspect [this issue](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/issues/985) is similar to the problem I encountered, and upgrading versions seems to have solved it.

The most visible part of the problem was the fact that a minified `actions.min.js` kept popping up in my static files, which seemed to not be the grappelli version of the `actions.js` file but the "vanilla" Django one, explaining the lack of the "Select all" functionality. I suspect a combination of my Django version and Grappelli caused this issue to be as annoying as it was. Version updates to both seem to be the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a full answer**

This is likely an issue caused by not creating namespaces for the static files. Quoting the Django's documentation:

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in `my_app/static/` (rather than creating another `my_app` subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the best way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.

> You can namespace static assets in `STATICFILES_DIRS` by specifying [prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs-prefixes).

If you created some custom JavaScript or CSS make sure you put them in a folder inside `static` folder with a different name. This way the file path will be unique and the file will be collected.

**UPDATE 1**

After diving into the static files of both Django's admin and Grappelli I found something interesting in Grappelli's `DateTimeShortcuts.js`. The content of this file is:

```
// dropped
// not used in grappelli
// kept this file to prevent 404
```

When prioritizing `grappelli` over `django.contrib.admin` this file overrides the original `DateTimeShortcuts.js` file provided by Django's admin. And there might be some differences between the files other than those specified by the warning which might cause such an unwanted behavior. The static files issue is caused by `grappelli` package.

Comment: These issues don't seem to arise from self-made javascript files, but from the (expected) conflict between some of the static files coming from Django's default packages and Grappelli's packages, which add functionality like what I'm looking to fix right now. Grappelli's are already prioritised, but a different minified version of the static file seems to be chosen when the DEBUG is set to False in settings.

Comment: You're totally right about it, I toke a look at files provided by Django's admin and Grappelli. I updated the answer to show what's wrong. Maybe you should open an issue on their Github repo?